# Module '"buffer"' has no exported member 'Blob' while building nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, winston

I am using Botpress 12 and I want to monitor logs using Elasticsearch and Kibana. However, I encountered an error while building my Botpress application when I attempted to implement log monitoring.

```
    import winston from 'winston'
    import { ElasticsearchTransport } from 'winston-elasticsearch'
    private printWinston() {
    const esTransportOpts = {
      // level: ["info", "warn", "error"], // Specify log level
      level: 'info',
      clientOpts: {
        node: 'http://localhost:9200',
        auth: {
          username: 'elastic',
          password: '*********'
        }
      }, // Elasticsearch client instance
      index: 'botpress-index', // Index name to store logs
      wait_for_active_shards: 1
      // ensureMappingTemplate: true,
    }

    // Create Winston logger with Elasticsearch transport
    let logger = winston.createLogger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(), // Log to console
        new ElasticsearchTransport(esTransportOpts) // Log to Elasticsearch
      ]
    })
    return logger
  }
```

I got error while building
[image: error]
[image]